# Redirection Error

Tags: performance, magento2.2.3

We built a website with Magento 2x version. We are monitoring our web server performance using Pingdom. Today, we got an alert message from Pingdom and it says the server is down for around 20 minutes.

When I check the root cause analysis for this outage, it says the downtime has occurred due to the **redirection error**. I'm not able to understand what the redirection error is. Could anyone please clarify me?